# How to use querystring as it look like below

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
var SearchUser = (from u in db.Users
                  join l in db.LoggedInUsers on u.UserID equals l.UserID
                  where u.Username==txtSearch.Text
                  select u).SingleOrDefault();

litUsers.Text = "<div style='background-color:#B0C4DE;color:red'>"
                + "<a href=\"ChatWindow.aspx\">" + SearchUser.Username + "</a></div>";
```

Now I would like to add some querystring to the anchor tag?
like I would like to add

session variable

Is this possible...............

Answer (score 2):

The query string is just anything that comes after "?". So for example:

```
litUsers.Text = "<div style='background-color:#B0C4DE;color:red'>"
            + "<a href=\"ChatWindow.aspx?user=" + SearchUser.UserId 
            + "\">" + SearchUser.Username + "</a></div>";
```

However, you need to be very careful when building URLs like this - you get the equivalent of a SQL injection attack, but in HTML. In other words, you need to know that UserId won't contain anything which needs escaping in a URL. (Likewise you need to be careful with SearchUser.Username, in terms of HTML escaping.)

Comment: Hehe, something dodgy with that querystring  :)